# Convert string to array of arrays in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, string

I have an input string and I need an output array of arrays, and I have been stuck. I tried using the "split()" function, but it wasn't giving me the desired output. Any answers would be appreciated!

input : `"[1,2,3] , [5,3,6,4] , [6,3,9,8]"`
Output : `[[1,2,3],[5,3,6,4],[6,3,9,8]]`

I am getting the input from an HTML input of type text, and I need an output of an array of arrays that are sorted.

I tried the below to get the answer -

```
let a=arrays.split(',');
```

Answer (score 2):

The input is very nearly valid JSON. It's just missing the square brackets to delimit the outer array. As such you can add those to the string then use `JSON.parse()` to deserialise the string to an array of objects:

```js
const input = "[1,2,3] , [5,3,6,4] , [6,3,9,8]";
const output = JSON.parse(`[${input}]`);

console.log(output);
```

Taking that a step further, if you wanted the child arrays to be sorted, you can call `sort()` on them:

```
output.forEach(a => a.sort());
```